# Optimization of angularjs function to load images on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two angularjs function in my dataContext object  that receive data from  an webapi as you can see below

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'datacontext';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
    ['common', datacontext]);

function datacontext(common) {
    var service = {

        getAllTagsByHttp: getAllTagsByHttp,
        getBlogPostsByHttp: getBlogPostsByHttp,
        getAllUserPicByHttp: getAllUserPicByHttp

    };
    return service;

    function getAllTagsByHttp() {
       return common.$http.get('/api/TagApi/alltags');         
    }

    function getBlogPostsByHttp() {
        return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllBlogPosts');
    }

    function getAllUserPicByHttp() {
        return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllUserPic');
    }   
}})();
```

I have an angularjs controller that call these api functions from the datacontext to receive information  to display back to the user. The getblogPost function is called first because the next function need's the data from this to operate on.the second function does a comparison on the first function's data to display back the img source to the user. The problem i am having is that it takes quite a few seconds for the second function to receive the data and  an complete its operation. The amount of data being send back is a few  records.Is there any improvements that can be made to controller or data Context object to reduce the time or improve the code?

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'search';
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller(controllerId, ['common','datacontext', search]);

function search(common, datacontext) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);


    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'search';
    vm.picData = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getBlogPosts(), getUserPicData(), getUserPicUrl()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Search View'); });
    }

    function getBlogPosts() {
        datacontext.getBlogPostsByHttp().then(function (response) {
            vm.data = response.data;               
        });
    }
    function getUserPicData() {
        datacontext.getAllUserPicByHttp().then(function (response) {
            vm.picData = response.data;

            for (var i = 0; vm.data.length > i; i++) {
                for (var x = 0; vm.picData.length > x; x++) {
                    if (vm.data[i].UserName == vm.picData[x].UserName) {
                        vm.data[i].PictureUrl = vm.picData[x].PictureUrl;
                       // console.log(vm.data[i].PictureUrl);
                        break;
                    }

                }                   
           }
        });
    }

   function getUserPicUrl(username) {
        getUserPicData();
        for (var i = 0; vm.picData.length < i; i++) {
            if (vm.picData[i].UserName === username) {
                return vm.picData[i].PictureUrl;
                }
            }
            return "not found";      
    }
}})();
```

Comment: If you can control the backend API, do the filtering on the backend.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy so less processing on the client side